# wordpress update permalinks structure

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination

I need to change my blog archive pagination url from:

**/blog/2**
to **blog/page/2**

This is our current permalink setup under Settings
Custom Structure - /blog/%postname%/

I don't have access to the server, htaccess, or the template files so trying to accomplish this inside functions.php

I am trying to use paginate_links filter to update the 'format' of my url string but does the $link argument have all the details of the paginate_links function, base, format..ect. I tried to use var_dump to see the $link array/object but nothing prints out to the screen.

```
// define the paginate_links callback 
function filter_paginate_links( $link ) { 
    // Blog page
    if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        var_dump($link);
        return $link; 
    }
    return $link;
};     
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'filter_paginate_links', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: `blog/page/2` is the default behavior/structure, isn't it? It is on my wordpress default installation. Maybe you're using a custom theme. If so, then let me know and I'll give you a solution!

Comment: That's what I thought too, using the Astra theme. Is there a way to update the path using the paginate_links filter? Is the $link arg just a string with the full URL. I just need a way to update the paginate_links function args 'format' at least that is the solution I came up with.

Comment: I just installed `Astra theme` and behaves exactly the same as the default wordpress. It gives me `blog/page/2` and `blog/page/3` etc. *"Is there a way to update the path using the paginate_links filter?"* well, it sounds legit, but can't tell you off the top of my head. Whenever I get a chance I'll work on it and let you know.